# Using xargs to make parallel curl API calls

Tags: bash, curl, xargs

When i run the following command:

```
seq 1 1 | xargs -I % -P 5 curl -k --user user:pass "https://localhost:port/api"
```

I only get one response back. I would have expected to get 5 responses since i'm running the curl command 5 times in parallel.

Is this correct or should i see 5 responses?

Comment: `-P 5` is "max 5" and you have only provided a single input, so only one call is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is on your `seq` command the range is from 1 to 1.

Try `seq 1 5` instead.

Comment: Yeah, the seq command stands for sequence. Starting at x and going until y. If my answer solves your problem, would you mind setting it as the accepted answer for the question?

Comment: Btw.: Alternatively, `seq 5` and `echo {1..5}` is also possible.

Comment: @DeanHouseholder do you know how I might send API calls to 3 different URLs in Parallel?

Comment: @loganengineer just put an `&` after the line and it will run the background. Refer to https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/jobs-bg-fg for an overview.  Example: `seq 1 5 | xargs -I % -P 5 curl -k --user user:pass "https://localhost:port/api" &`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need to specify & repeat number of processes in `-P` option. Just use `-P 0` to allow it to run as many processes as possible. You also don't need to use `seq`, just use `printf` like this in process substitution:

```bash
xargs -I % -P 0 curl -k --user user:pass "https://localhost:port/api" \
< <(printf '%s\n' {1..5})
```